# Input in LLVM, I think I do not understand dominance and the location of phi nodes

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

My goal is to do something simple in LLVM.  I want to, using the C library function getchar, define an LLVM function that reads an input from the commandline.  Here is my algorithm in pseudocode:

```
getInt:
  get a character, set the value to VAL
  check if VAL is '-'
    if yes then set SGN to -1 and set VAL to the next character else set SGN to 1
  set NV = to the next char minus 48
  while (NV >= 0) // 48 is the first ASCII character that represents a number
    set VAL = VAL*10
    set VAL = VAL + NV
    set NV to the next char minus 48
  return SGN*VAL
```

So now, the LLVM code I come up with for doing this is in my head the most straightforward way to translate the above into LLVM IR.  However, I get the error 
"PHI nodes not grouped at the top of the basic block."  If I move some things around to fix this error, I get errors about dominance.  Below is the LLVM IR code that gives me the PHI nodes error.  I believe I am misunderstanding something basic about LLVM IR, so any help you can give is super appreciated.

```
define i32 @getIntLoop() {
_L1:
  %0 = call i32 @getchar()
  %1 = phi i32 [ %0, %_L1 ], [ %3, %_L2 ], [ %8, %_L4 ]
  %2 = icmp eq i32 %1, 45
  br i1 %2, label %_L2, label %_L5

_L2:                                              ; preds = %_L1
  %3 = call i32 @getchar()
  br label %_L3

_L3:                                              ; preds = %_L4, %_L2
  %4 = call i32 @getchar()
  %5 = icmp slt i32 %4, 40
  br i1 %5, label %_L5, label %_L4

_L4:                                              ; preds = %_L3
  %6 = sub i32 %4, 48
  %7 = mul i32 %1, 10
  %8 = add i32 %6, %7
  br label %_L3

_L5:                                              ; preds = %_L3, %_L1
  br i1 %2, label %_L6, label %_L7

_L6:                                              ; preds = %_L5
  %9 = mul i32 -1, %1
  ret i32 %9

_L7:                                              ; preds = %_L5
  ret i32 %1
}
```

Comment: A shameless self-plug: if this is your first work with LLVM IR, you might be interested in first prototyping your code by hand using [an IR editor](http://amishne.github.io/llvm-ir-editor/), that will give you instant feedback about things like domination issues. However, I confess that one of the best ways to learn the IR is just by writing C snippets and taking a look at the generated IR from Clang. The IR is not trivial, especially if you have no prior experience with SSA form, and learning by example is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a very clear error, though. According to the LLVM IR [language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#phi-instruction):

> There must be no non-phi instructions between the start of a basic
>   block and the PHI instructions: i.e. PHI instructions must be first in
>   a basic block.

You have a `phi` in `L1` which violates this.

Why does it have `%_L1` as one of its sources? There are no jumps to `%_L1` anywhere else. I think you should first understand how `phi` works, possibly by compiling small pieces of C code into LLVM IR with Clang and see what gets generated.

Put simply, a `phi` is needed to have consistency in SSA form while being able to assign one of several values into the same register. Make sure you read about [SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) - it explains Phi node as well. And additional good resource is the LLVM tutorial which you should go through. In particular, [part 5 covers Phis](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl5.html). As suggested above, running small pieces of C through Clang is a great way to understand how things work. This is in no way "hacky" - it's the scientific method! You read the theory, think hard about it, form hypotheses about how things work and then verify those hypotheses by running Clang and seeing what it generates for real-life control flow.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what the error is.  I do not know a way around it.

Comment: What I want is to have a variable, like VAL in the pseudo-code that is initialized to the result of getchar.  I admit, that this is probably a mistake in design.  What I would like to know is how to view the problem in LLVM, so that I can come up with a correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about CLANG.  However, I rarely learn efficiently that way.  I prefer to understand the way things are intended to be, rather than hacking my way to understanding.  I can be a bit obsessive about wanting to understand things in the cleanest way possible.  That is why I posted the question here.  On a side note, I have a way of writing this function in LLVM, just not  one that corresponds to my intuition of how it should be done.  Any further feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried compiling with Clang, and what I got was exactly what I thought I would get, and what I didn't want.  The IR generated by Clang allocates variables, and uses store and load to update and access these variables -- no phi used.  In the end this does not help me understand LLVM unfortunately.

Comment: While the way Clang compiles this statement is certainly a more robust solution, and is, as far as I can see, the only way to sanely write a compiler backend in LLVM... I would still like to know how to perform this function in LLVM in a more direct manner.  Just for educational purposes.

Comment: @ArmUser: run clang with optimizations, or run `opt` after clang. The "mem2reg" pass runs during optimizations and converts allocas to LLVM registers.

Comment: That is really awesome!!  Thank you for the help.  Is there any disadvantage to using the allocas and optimization opposed to manipulating the LLVM registers directly?

Comment: @ArmUser: the tutorial I linked to earlier discusses this, I think. Generally, using memory is probably easier to do manually.